# Website encountered unexpected error - how to avoid?

Tags: 7, database, cron

I'm having that typical problem of `Website encountered unexpected error` popping up sometimes and then after repairing `watchdog` MySQL table it all works find again.

My question is if there is a module that would do this automatically? Or any script that I could run from cron or from drupal?

I installed `db maintenance` module and thought it does that, but apparently no.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Does MySQL crash after that error? Either way your watchdog table is being corrupted. Are you running out of disk space? Make sure you are using InnoDB tables; MyISAM is prone to corruption.

You can check your table type by running this from a MySQL command prompt and looking for the Engine= parameter.

```
mysql> show create table watchdog;
```

You can also disable dblog and enable syslog instead. Syslog writes to your system logs and is much more scalable for higher traffic sites. See if that solves your problem.